# How to simplify $(\cos x -\sin x)\left(2\tan x +\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)+2 = 0$ to get a general solution?

Tags: trigonometry

I need to solve this trigonometric equation to get a general solution

$$(\cos x -\sin x)\left(2\tan x +\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)+2 = 0$$

I tried simplifying using the usual submultiple and multiple angle formula but cant seem to be able to express it as a single function to get the solution.

Don't think factorisation works either...how do I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify that $x=\pi(2m+1),m\in\mathbb{Z},$ are not solutions to the equation, then use the tangent [half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) $t=\tan\frac x2$ to rewrite the equation in terms of $t$ (for $\tan x$ use the double-angle identity):
$$\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}-\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)\left(2\cdot\frac{2t}{1-t^2}+\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}\right)+2=0 $$
After clearing denominators and factorizing, this simplifies to
$$(3t^2-1)(t^2+2t+3)=0 $$
So the solutions are $t=\tan\frac x2=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$ which gives us $\dfrac x2=\pm\dfrac \pi 6+k\pi \Leftrightarrow x=\pm\dfrac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$.